# Netsuite Newbie: picking your attention about netsuite

Tags: netsuite

1. do you have any idea what's the default currency rate in netsuite?,

   2. also in inventory item display "total value" field, any idea how the computation is? or how it's use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The default currency in Netsuite is Dollar. you can change it in customization ? my company.

Also for second question Netsuite allow conversions on the bases of exchange rate. You have to enable Multiple Currencies feature from My Company > Enable Feature and also then enable automatic conversions.

Answer (score -1):

1) On NetSuite, if you go to Setup -> Company -> Company Information, you'll see your currency setting for your company profile. Please be aware that if you have multiple subsidiaries, the currencies could differ per subsidiary.

2) If you click on the field label - you'll see more detail on the field, including how the value is calculated:

[image]

Comment: yup, i already read the help description but my concern is, why there's a number "45" included in the computation, where it came from?., i didn't put 45 anywhere else or it is a built-in (in our netsuite config, but i'm still learning the process) ?

i.e:
- Peso computation:
total cost divided by 45 = total value

- USD computation:
purchase price * exchange rate = total cost
total cost divided by 45 = total value

---- this is actually the computation formula to find out the total cost in our end.

Comment: Where are you seeing this formula with the 45?

Comment: we figured-out that 45 or 0.02222 (converted from peso to dollar) is like a built-in number upon calculating total value in our netsuite web-app. thanks for your time, i'll catch up with you soon . thanks again